# Error installing plugin sbt 1.0 sbt-idea 1.6.0

Tags: sbt, spray

I need some help on these, I clone this repository
https://github.com/oermolaev/simple-scala-rest-example
But when I run sbt I got such errors:
Interesting I could not run maybe some repository is outdated... If you could help me I would be very glad

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
    "Sonatype releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
)

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.0")

```
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\workspace\simple-scala-rest-example\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/workspace/simple-scala-rest-example/project/}simple-scala-rest-example-build...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  1
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.6.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.9.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.6.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\workspace\simple-scala-rest-example\project\plugins.sbt#L6-7)
[warn]            +- default:simple-scala-rest-example-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.9.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\workspace\simple-scala-rest-example\project\plugins.sbt#L8-9)
[warn]            +- default:simple-scala-rest-example-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]
[error] unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:229)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:190)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:185)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:182)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:38)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:91)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:87)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? [error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]
[error] unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
[error]         1
```

I need help on install such plugin here.
thanks

ps why is so HARD to ask questions here it took more than 20 minutes trying to hit the publish button! comeon

Comment: Dude, that repo was updated 4 years !!! ago :)
For example, at the moment, sbt-assembly repo https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly says the latest version is 0.14.6.
So look at the dependencies that project uses, manually specify more or less up to date versions and try `reload update` in SBT console.

Comment: I was trying to study spray and slick, best documentation unfortunately I found from Oleg even though its old its very good for beginners like me. The trick was changing sbt.version

Answer (score 0):

Well I explain what I did
Changed sbt.version to 0.13.7 inside build properties.
My machine was on java 9, downloaded good old jdk1.8 from Oracle archive and installed.
git clone
sbt on project
plugin to 1.6.0

and ran

thanks